# openERP wizard issue with html iframe

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

i'm developing django website and embed [OpenERP](https://www.openerp.com/) using `<iframe>` tag.

**Example :**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>my website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>my website content </h3>
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.54:8069/" width="1024" height="600"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

create wizard(ex. sale order lines/) not open. Display error on browser console window something like

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   `"http://192.168.1.54:8069"` from accessing a frame with origin "null". 
>   The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

try V6 and V7 but in both case it's not work

this issue is related to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) how can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Working on the same issue. Seem you'd have to configure enable cors config for the openerp web-server. Although I have figured out how to do it with my own web-server but cannot do so for the openerp web-server. See more at the [CORS website](http://enable-cors.org/index.html)

Comment: plz add some example how can i add CORS in other server